# No method found "op_addition"

Tags: powershell, collections

I want to add a specific selection of data in a variable like this:

```
$a = Get-Service | select -First 10 | ? Name -Like "App*"
$collection = $null
foreach($item in $a){
  if($item.Status -like "Running"){
    $collection = $collection + $item
  }
}
```

When trying to run I got an error like:

> No method found "op_addition"

What can I do to save my selection in a separate variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, `$collection` is `$null`.

Then, after the first loop iteration, `$collection` is a single `ServiceController` object, since `$null + $object` is just `$object`.

On the second loop iteration, it fails because `ServiceController` don't have any overloads for `+`, just as the error informs you.

You'll need to declare `$collection` an actual collection (you can use the `@()` array subexpression operator) for `+` to work they way you expect:

```
$a = Get-Service | select -First 10 | ? Name -Like "App*"
$collection = @()
foreach($item in $a){
  if($item.Status -like "Running"){
    $collection = $collection + $item
  }
}
```

Alternatively, assign all the output from the loop directly to `$collection`:

```
$a = Get-Service | select -First 10 | ? Name -Like "App*"
$collection = foreach($item in $a){
  if($item.Status -like "Running"){
    $item
  }
}
```

Which could of course be simplified with a single `Where-Object` statement in the pipeline:

```
$collection = Get-Service App* |Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Running'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When switching `$collection = $null` to `$collection = @()` I dont get the error message anymore. Unfortunately the variable `$collection` has no content ... Do you have an idea why?

Comment: And you know for a fact that the first 10 services returned by `Get-Service` contains at least 1 service named App* that is running?

Comment: My gosh! I've made a stupid mistake. Working with a GUI and using popups checking if everything is fine. Here, collections are not displayed in a popup, so I thought the variable was empty. Everything is working, thanks again!